# Regex for matches 0 and 1 where consecutive 1s must be odd?

Tags: regex

I would like to write a regex that can match binary string where consecutive 1s must have odd length.

Examples: 1001110111 is accepted, and 10110111 is not accepted.

```
(1(11)*|0*)*
```

The best I came up with is the one above, which is not correct. This regex will match consecutive even 1s too. Any other ideas?

TIA

Comment: `^(?!.*(?<!1)(?:1{2})+(?!1))[01]*$` or `^(?!.*(?:0|^)(?:1{2})+(?:0|$))[01]*$`

Comment: It will match consecutive because there are no boundaries or anchors. When it fails to match from the first position, it just starts at the next.

Comment: What language are you using and why do you want to use a regex?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex for this with a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!(?:[01]*0)?(?:1{2})+(?:0|$))[01]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c8GCfj/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?!(?:[01]*0)?(?:1{2})+(?:0|$))`: Expression to fail the match when you have even number of `1`s in the expression anywhere. `(?:1{2})+` matches a pair of `1`s
- `(?:0|$)` ensures pair of `1`s is not followed by `1`
- `(?:[01]*0)?`: only allows presence of `0` or start just before `1`s
- `[01]+`: Match a string with 0 or 1 with one or more length

Answer (score 1):

I think another option could be to match either only zeroes or match optional leading zeroes and repeat matching odd 1's followed by either 1+ zeroes or the end of the string.

```
^(?:(?:0*1(?:11)*(?:0+|$))+|0+)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `0*1(?:11)*` Match 0+ zeroes, `1` and repeat 0+ times `11`
    - `(?:0+|$)` Match 1+ zeroes or assert end of string
  - `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times to not match empty strings
  - `|` Or
  - `0+` Match only zeroes
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aPdGHS/1)

Answer (score 1):

This should not need the complications of the lookaround solutions. The basic problem with your attempted solution is the `0*` which can match zero `0`s before the next group of `1`s.

```
0*(1(11)*0+)*(1(11)*)?
```

This handles leading `0`s. If you're not concerned about that you can remove the `0*`.

The "meat" is the inner expression with the `0+`. Odd groups of `1`s delimited by one or more `0`s.

Since those groups end with `0`, we need an optional odd group of `1`s at the end in case the string ends in `1`.

Note that as all quantities above are optional, the above solution will also match an empty string. If you require at least one `1`, it's a little more complicated:

```
0*1(11)*(0+1(11)*)*0*
```

Answer (score 1):

If your regex flavor supports [possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) for preventing backtracking.

```
^0*(?:(?:11)*+10*)*$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/amyAjG/1)

Be aware, that this one will also match an empty string. 
If the string should always start with `1` and contain one or more characters, try [`^(?:(?:11)*+10*)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/amyAjG/2)